# Why Am I getting java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.rsa.jsafe.CryptoJ.isNativeAvailable(Ljava/lang/String;) in Documentum

Tags: java, documentum

I am using Documentum 7 , and getting this exception when trying to login to documentum

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.rsa.jsafe.CryptoJ.isNativeAvailable(Ljava/lang/String;)

I have so far worked on below possibilities but everything seems to be in place

this could be because of many reasons

1.You have new jar in you project and you compile your code with it but when you deploy to server  , it has old jar file in it's class path , and the class loader has loaded the old jar file which doesn't have this new method in the specified class.

2.You may have two version of same jar file in your class path , an older version and a newer version.

3.I also have dfc.properties file in my classpath.

Can anybody help what might be going wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After banging my head with the wall for so many days , I am lucky to find the solution which is to copy the latest dfc.properties from my Documentum installation folder and copy another file called dfc.keystore in my classpath. And this has resolved my problem. Looks like the files I already had in my classpath got corrupted or something to copying fresh files from the documentum installation folder did the trick for me.

Comment: did you tried just delete dfc.keysore? it should have the same effect (it'll recreate after client restart)

Comment: Did you mean to delete the dfc.keystore from my documentum config folder ? I didn't try that , but this is interesting. Actually I am still wondering what could be the reason behind this error :) , can you please enlighten me about the reasons which may have caused this issue?